# Finding the closest polyline to a given point

Tags: java, android, performance, google-maps, polyline

I'm working on an android app which uses the Google Maps API.

I'm looking for an algorithm which would help me find the closest polyline to a given point. I've a map with 100 polylines, and I would like to find the closest polyline to a given point.

An example would be in the following picture where the red dot is the location and the blue lines are some of the polylines. I have access to all the points on the polyline. I was thinking to leverage the starting and ending point somehow but I'm not sure how to.

[image]

At the moment I'm simply iterating over all the list of polylines, but it's not very efficient and I'm looking to improve the performance of the application
Sample code:

```
        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<List<LatLng>>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            entry.getValue().stream().parallel().forEach(obj -> {
                boolean isonPath = PolyUtil.isLocationOnPath(currentLocation, obj, true, 100);
                if (isonPath) {
//                do something if the point is on the path
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: `//                do something if the point is on the path` That is something different from the closest polyline i would say.

Comment: How many polylines? And how many points intotal?

Comment: @blackapps that is the second part of the functionality of this application. The idea is lets say there are 100 polylines, and each polyline would have 100 points. If my point is on the polyline do action. At the moment i'm iterating through all of them as shown in the sample code and i agree my comment would state to do something else. But i'm just wondering is there such algorithm which would help me find the closest polyline, so i'd have to iterate only over the point from that polyline rather than iterating over all the points of all the polylines.

Comment: How long does it take to examine 100x100 points?

Comment: I have not benchmarked it, but it just doesn't seem right to go over all of them, this is why i'm looking for a more performant way of doing it.

Comment: Consider using a geohash; compute geohash on all points as you are building your polylines (once); then for any given point the problem becomes find the nearest neighbor for any given pt (red dot).  The advantage gained is the geohash on all points is computed once (and less complex than a distance calculation) and a nearest neighbor can be computed easily for any given point.  The hash function would require sufficient precision to reduce nearest neighbor collisions to an acceptable number (e.g. 10's of meters).  This is how proximity queries work with geohashes.

Comment: `it just doesn't seem right to go over all of them,`. Why not? If it can be done in an acceptable time why looking further? But if you dont even know the time needed... Your phone probably has eight cores. Use them.

Comment: Andy Thank you for the suggestion I will start looking into it.
blackapps it seems to be working fine on a pixel 3xl virtual emulator, i'd like it to work even on the lower spec'd phones. I will try to run some benchmarks on that to see how long it takes, and also, I will try to see if i can run it on a lower spec'd device to see what's the behaviour there.